# Dropzone - How to remove files?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

how can I remove the uploaded files and previewed thumbnails? That´s my code.
The alert works, but the thumbs are not hiding.

```
        new Dropzone("form#galerie", {
                url: "/business/kleinanzeigen/upload",
                maxFilesize: 5,
                maxFiles: 10,
                acceptedFiles: '.png, .gif, .jpg',
                complete: function (success) {
                    vm.form.galerie.push(JSON.parse(success.xhr.response))
                },
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                removedfile: function (file) {
                    //console.log(file);
                    alert('works');
                    this.removeFile(file);
                }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your removedFile function doesn't seem right. It should be something like this:

```
removedfile: function(f) {
var reference;
return (reference = f.previewElement) != null ? reference.parentNode.removeChild(f.previewElement) : void 0;
```

}